# How to log the longer text in Firebase events?

Tags: android, firebase, text, firebase-analytics

I am working Firebase event log I was able to see my logs and wanted to print a unique id whose length is 42. but when I added this to event then its giving me following error

```
Value is too long; discarded. Value kind, name, value length: param, item_id, 42


Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, api_ID);
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, transaction_ID);
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, transaction_ID);
        MyApplication.getFirebaseAnalytics().logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

I understand the error, suggest any other way to log the id (length is 42).

All answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: updated,Please check the code now @ChiragRaval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the latest Firebase document, Param values can be up to 100 characters long.

Please make sure you are using the latest firebase library in gradle.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param

Comment: I have updated to 11.0.0 but getting this error Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null} E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service